# Write list to column

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

The data are presented in the format

```
tags_list = [
    ['foo'],
    ['foo', 'boo', 'goo'],
    ['boo', 'zoo']
]
```

How can I fill the column `tags TEXT[]`?
I'm trying to do something like

```
cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO tags_table VALUES (%s);""", tags_list)
```

but it throws an exception `not all arguments converted during string formatting`.

Input data format can be modified by any ways, of course.

---

**UPDATE**

Ok, I'm doing this:

```
for tags in tags_list:
    tags_literal = '{"' + '","'.join(tags) + '"}'
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO tags_data VALUES (%s);""", (tags_literal,))
```

BUT rows in table looks like this:

```
(['foo'],)
(['foo', 'boo', 'goo'],)
(['boo', 'zoo'],)
```

while I'm expecting followed:

```
{'foo'}
{'foo', 'boo', 'goo'}
{'boo', 'zoo'}
```

any ideas? :)

Comment: What is the schema of your tags_table?

Comment: @HavanAgrawal there is only one column `tags TEXT[]` for testing

Comment: Are you saying that a database column has the type "TEXT array"? Or is it just TEXT?

Comment: @HavanAgrawal here is creation query: `cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE tags_table (tags TEXT[]);""")`

Comment: try putting a comma after tags_list

Comment: You need the list of tuples to use it in the `executemany()`, so try `tags_list = [(['foo'],), (['foo', 'boo', 'goo'],), (['boo', 'zoo'],)]`

Comment: Are you trying to insert many rows or just one row? If your trying to insert just one row use cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO tags_table VALUES (%s);""", (tags_list,))

Comment: @Tim many. it is desirable to perform only one query for the entire list of lists, if possible

Comment: @AntoshaShmonoff, Abelisto's comment in the answer should work for you then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this comment: *"it is desirable to perform only one query for the entire list of lists, if possible"*

Yes, it is possible, but you need to build the `insert` statement by hands. Like this:

```
tags_list = [['foo'], ['foo', 'boo', 'goo'], ['boo', 'zoo']]

# I am not Python guru, probably there is more elegant solution

s = 'insert into tags_table values' + ','.join(['(%s)'] * len(tags_list))
print s

# Output: insert into tags_table values(%s),(%s),(%s)

cur.execute(s, tags_list)
```

---

And how it should be using loop:

```
for tags in tags_list:
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO tags_data VALUES (%s);""", (tags,))
```

Answer (score 2):

Going by what I read [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html), the following should work:

```
for tags in tags_list:
    tags_with_quotes = ['"' + tag + '"' for tag in tags]
    tags_literal = "{" + ",".join(tags_with_quotes) + "}"
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tags_table VALUES (%s);", (tags_literal,))
```

Comment: Edited the answer slightly? Can you should try again?

Comment: `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tags_table VALUES ('%s');", (tags,))` should be enough.

Comment: @Abelisto your solution works without quotes around %s, but results row becomes `[(['foo'],), (['foo', 'boo', 'goo'],), (['boo', 'zoo'],)]`

Comment: @AntoshaShmonoff I suppose that you trying something like `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tags_table VALUES (%s);", (tags_list,))`. I meant to replace the loop body mentioned in the answer to `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tags_table VALUES (%s);", (tags,))`

Comment: Edited answer according to @Abelisto 's suggestion

Answer (score 2):

If you parameterize `executemany()` with a list of parameter lists:

- all these inner lists have to have the same exact length
- the number of parameters need to be equal to the number of placeholders

In other words, in the current state it's not going to work since your inner lists have different lengths and only a single placeholder in the query.

Making all inner lists to contain a single-item-tuples should make it work:

```
tags_list = [
    (['foo'], ),
    (['foo', 'boo', 'goo'], ),
    (['boo', 'zoo'], )
]
cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO tags_table VALUES (%s);""", tags_list)
```